# linked lists, value, add and remove

Tags: c, list

How do I modify the code below to insert a element with value 25 after the
element with value 20, and remove element w/value 15 from the list? I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help! 
main.c

```
#include "includes.h"
ListType list[5];
int main()
{
 ListType list[5];
 list[0].value = 0; list[0].next = list+1;
 list[1].value = 10; list[1].next = list+2;
 list[2].value = 20; list[2].next = NULL;
 ListReport(list);
 // Insert an element
 list[3].value = 15; list[3].next = list+2;
 list[1].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 // Remove an element
 list[0].next = list+3;
 ListReport(list);
 return 0;
}
// Report values in linked lisk
void ListReport(ListType *plist)
{
 int nn = 0;
 printf("ListReport\n");
 while(plist != NULL){
 printf("%d, value = %d\n",nn++, plist->value);
 plist = plist->next;
 }
}
```

includes.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct entry
 {
 int value;
 struct entry *next;
 } ListType;
 void ListReport(ListType *plist);

// end of includes.h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Insert
list[4].value = 20; 
list[2].next = list+3;
list[4].next = NULL;

// Delete
list[1].next = list+2;
```